# How do I use a timing function within an animation on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I want to use a timing function lets say kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut

My aim is I have start point (X1,Y1) and end point (X2,Y2) and I want a ease function which will provide the easing functionality over this points range. Like varying the (X,Y) range and giving me a curve from start to end.

How to do that in iPhone.
Like in the following article

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/

we can see the blocks moving, I want something like that.

Comment: Are you talking about animations you'd like to apply to core animation layers or to views?  They function a bit differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is a good starting point for you:

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/23/nstimer-the-poor-mans-threading-code-snapshot/

Comment: Well this is being done by user. I am talking about how to use the inbuilt library for that. Inbuilt library something similar to timing functions.

Answer (score 6):

When animating the movement of a UIView within a begin / commit animation block, you can use the following method to set the animation timing curve:

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

When animating a layer via CAAnimation, you can use the following to set the timing function there:

```
[animation setTimingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

Finally, when wrapping a series of animations in a CATransaction, you can use the following to set the coordinated timing function of all the animations:

```
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

Comment: [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut] 

does not work anymore, one has to use the following instead:

[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];